# Clojure Ahead-of-Time compilation fails for Java classes "No matching method ofInstant found taking 2 args for class java.time.LocalDate"

Tags: java, clojure, ahead-of-time-compile

Attempting to AOT compile a Clojure namespace with `clj -e "(compile 'my-ns.core)"` throws an exception when attempting to construct a `LocalDate`:

```
Syntax error (IllegalArgumentException) compiling . at (my-project/my-ns-core.clj:5:1).
No matching method ofInstant found taking 2 args for class java.time.LocalDate
```

Works fine in REPL. Why failing in AOT? Classes are imported.

```
(ns my-ns.core
  (:require [clojure.alpha.spec.gen :as g])
  (:import (java.time LocalDate))

(LocalDate/ofInstant (Instant/ofEpochMilli 123) (ZoneId/of "UTC"))
```

I assume this must be related to these classes being included from the AOT build?

Answer (score 1):

GraalVM was in my `$PATH` which took precedence for calls to `java` with an older Java version that did not include the Java 8 date classes. Figured it out by running `which java`.

Solved with:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Users/<username>/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-15/Contents/Home`
```

And not including `$GRAALVM_HOME` in `$PATH`.